# Make a virtual raster

Tags: qgis

I know this is a very simple question, but how do I make a virtual raster in the latest version of QGIS (3.0)? The help files are for an older version of the program and they seemed to have some things around in the menus since they wrote them

Answer (score 3):

Processing toolbox | GDAL | Raster Misc. | Build Virtual Raster

[image]

Comment: And were are toolboxes found?

Comment: In Processing - https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing/intro.html

Comment: Are you sure you're not giving an answer for a previous version?

Comment: Unless I'm seriously missing something, there is no processing drop down menu in the current version (the webpage you sited is not current)

Comment: Nope. Screenshot is from my pc with qgis 3 installed and help link is the current 3.x help. Have you got the core processing plugin enabled?

Comment: No, it's glitched and won't load

Comment: Is there any way around this?

Comment: Honestly, 3.0 seems like it was rushed and not ready for release

Comment: Actually, the stability issues were noted in the download page, I just didn't read carefully enough. Going to install the older, stable version

Comment: The processing menu is a core plugin, so you may have to enable it from the plugin menu > manage and install plugins.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently trying to determine if you can still use the recursive by directory option as I can't see it in the latest version.

I note this question is pretty old and things have probably moved on but in case anyone is still looking for these tools you can also type '. raster' into the box in the bottom left and you should be able to find the function that way as well.

I also have the option under the Raster > Miscellaneous Menu.